# ¿copiar un archivo al directorio tmp, linux?

Tags: linux, archivo, unix

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado copiar mi archivo hellow_world, en el directorio tmp y no he podido, encontré que podía copiar poniendo

`cp source_hello_world destination_tmp`

y lo que me indica es que el archivo hello_world no es un directorio entonces seguí buscando y me salió que coloque

`cp hello_world tmp`

o sea que ponga el archivo a copiar y el destino y lo que paso es que se creo un archivo tmp nada mas o no se si ese sea el directorio tmp (tengo por conocimiento que tmp es un directorio que contiene archivos de los que se requieren solo temporalmente), estoy algo confundido,

Comment: solucionado mi gente gracias

Comment: La respuesta se pone en las respuestas para ayudarle a otros en el futuro a resolver tu mismo problema. Puedes marcarla como aceptada y tal :)

Answer (score 0):

cp necesita  
por lo que vi en tu comandos, intentas copiar archivos a la raiz /tmp

pues solo comando es simple

cp -r carpeta_origen /tmp
Esto copiará la carpeta a la raiz /tmp con su mismo nombre, si quisieras cambiar el nombre solo tendrías que escribir en destino /tmp/copia_carpeta_origen.

Saludos